# How can I run vs2022 and vs2022 Preview on the same machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

How can I run vs2022 and vs2022 Preview on the same machine?

I need PREVIEW for trying .NET MAUI and vs2022 for my release projects.

Comment: OS = Windows 10

Comment: I just found out about VS2022 preview, after Googling "where has my code preview gone from VS2022"?! Now I find out these are two separate products! WHY MS!? Why do they need to keep "fixing" what ain't broken

Answer (score 0):

OK managed - actually was simple.  It accepts both.  However, it's bad that MS does not allow MAUI preview on the production 2022.